# zip how to include files with a dollar sign in the name

Tags: zip, solaris

Oracle Solaris 10 9/10 SPARC

I'm trying to archive and compress a large directory using zip

```
zip dir dir
```

in this directory are some files with a dollarsign like name$whatever. Zip skips those files with an error message

```
 name not matched.
```

Is there a way to prevent this and have those file included? It's not a problem if the dollar is renamed to some unique string and converted back later.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: sorry should have been first, updated question.

Comment: Did you try zip -r (for recursion)?

Comment: yes I also tried -r. It works with tar and then gzip.